# Extract a part of a line from a log file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

What is the fastest way to extract a substring of interest from input such as the following?

```
MsgTrace(65/26)noop:user=xxx=INBOX:cmd=534
ImapFetchComplete(56/39)user=xxxxxxxxxx
```

Desired output (i.e., the `:`-terminated string following the string `MsgTrace(65/26)` in this example):

`noop`

I tried the following, but without success:

```
egrep -i "[a-zA-Z]+\(.*\)[a-z]+:"
```

Comment: Why did you combine `-i` and `[a-zA-Z]`? Also when your pattern extracts *nothing*, why do you ask for the *fastest* way instead of just asking for *any* way? Given that, how should the title of your question read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` by default returns the *entire line* when a match is found on a given input line.

While option `-o` restricts the output to only that part of the line that the regex matched, that is still not enough in this case, because you want a *substring* of that match.

However, since you're on Linux, you can use GNU `grep`'s `-P` option (for support of [PCREs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcrepattern), Perl-compatible regular expression), which allows extracting a *submatch* by way of features such as `\K` (drop everything matched so far) and `(?=...)` (a look-ahead assertion that does not contribute to the match):

```
$ grep -Po  "[a-zA-Z]\(.*\)\K[a-z]+(?=:)" <<'EOF'
MsgTrace(65/26)noop:user=xxx=INBOX:cmd=534
ImapFetchComplete(56/39)user=xxxxxxxxxx
EOF
noop  # output
```

---

#### Optional background information:

[Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) points out (in a since-deleted comment) that GNU `grep`'s `man` page still calls the `-P` option "highly experimental" that may "warn of unimplemented features", but the option has been around for years, and in practice I have yet to see a warning or a performance problem - YMMV.

In the case at hand, the above command even outperforms `sed` and `awk` solutions - see [NeronLeVelu's helpful performance comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41736692/45375).

The [interesting article](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) Ed points to discusses a potential performance problem that *can* surface with regex engines such as used by `grep -P` (via the PCRE library), Perl itself, and many other widely used (and mature) regex engines, such as in Python, Ruby, and PHP:

- In short: the recursive backtracking algorithm employed by these engines can result in severe performance degradation with "pathological" regexes that string together long sequences of subexpressions with variable-length quantifiers, such as (a longer version of) `a?a?a?a?aaaa` to match `aaaa`.
- The article argues that backtracking is only truly required when a regex contains backreferences, and that a different, much faster algorithm should be employed in their absence.

Comment: On performance maybe see the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/77818891/6607497 with an answer that improved the `sed` processing time by a factor of 1700.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
$ sed -n 's/[[:alpha:]]*([^)]*)\([[:lower:]]*\):.*/\1/p' file
noop
```

It's portable to all POSIX seds and doesn't employ PCREs, just BREs, so the regexp matching part at least should be fast.

Alternatively, using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[[:alpha:]]*\([^)]*)([[:lower:]]*):/,a){print a[1]}' file
noop
```

Comment: When just printing the capture group, isn't the trailing `.*` unnecessary?

Comment: @U.Windl I'm not just printing the capture group, I'm replacing whatever the regexp matches with the capture group and then printing the transformed input line, so if I didn't include `.*` in the regexp then everything after the capture group (i.e. from `:` to the end of the line) would remain in the output. I just added a gawk alternative which IS just printing the capture group so you can see the difference in the regexps.

Comment: Sorry, seems I didn't look close enough.

Answer (score 2):

Little quick and dirty test on a 2469120 lines text of such a sample entry give `grep -PO` as winner

```
time sed -n -e 's/^MsgTrace[^)]\{4,\})//;t M' -e 'b' -e ':M' -e 's/:.*//p' YourFile >/dev/null
real    0m7.61s
user    0m7:10s
sys     0m0.13s

time awk -F ':' '/^MsgTrace/{ sub( /.*)/, "", $1); print $1}' YourFile >/dev/null
real    0m17.43s
user    0m16.19s
sys     0m0.17s

time grep -Po  "[a-zA-Z]\(.*\)\K[a-z]+(?=:)" YourFile >/dev/null
real    0m6.72s
user    0m6.23s
sys     0m0.11s

time sed -n 's/[[:alpha:]]*([^)]*)\([[:lower:]]*\):.*/\1/p' YourFile >/dev/null
real    0m17.43s
user    0m16.29s
sys     0m0.12s

time grep -Po '(?<=MsgTrace\(65/26\)).*?(?=:)' YourFile >/dev/null
real    0m16.38s
user    0m15.22s
sys     0m0.15s
```

for @EdMorton question (i redo the same original sed to have compare value in same context of machine load). The exact string is lot faster, i imagine that sed try several combination before selecting which is the longest one for all criteria where a `.*l` give lot more possibility than `pool is full`

```
time sed -n -e 's/^MsgTrace([^)]\{3,\})//;T' -e 's/:.*//p' YourFile >/dev/null
real    0m7.28s
user    0m6.60s
sys     0m0.13s

time sed -n -e 's/^[[:alpha:]]*([^)]\{3,\})//;T' -e 's/:.*//p' YourFile >/dev/null
real    0m10.44s
user    0m9.67s
sys     0m0.14s

time sed -n -e 's/^[[:alpha:]]*([^)]*)//;T' -e 's/:.*//p' YourFile >/dev/null

real    0m10.54s
user    0m9.75s
sys     0m0.11s
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this - interesting findings. Intriguing how much the look-behind assertion slows the `grep` solution down (even though the timing is still competitive).

Comment: Its also interesting the time difference between the 2 sed commands where the one with just 1 instruction takes 17 secs but the one with a series of 4 instructions takes 7 secs. I believe it's what you saw but I can't imagine why that would be. Hmm, I wonder if using character classes ([[:alpha:]]) instead of character ranges ([a-zA-Z]) or specific strings (MsgTrace) is what's REALLY making the difference. It'd be interesting to see the timing if they were all using the specific string for MsgTrace and just `[^:]*` for the matching part (as opposed to `[[:lower:]]` or `[a-z]`).

Comment: @EdMorton added some test about your comment

Comment: Did you try to improve the performance of the winner even further by using a non-greedy match instead of `.*`?