# What is causing the inefficiency of GNU sed using `.*` substitutions?

Tags: regex, performance, sed, substitution

SLES features a [`supportconfig`](https://github.com/openSUSE/supportutils/blob/63bac1302f1d9dd38feca01da8398bf49c7becb2/bin/supportconfig) command that was found to be very slow when creating the "Updates". First examination showed that `sed` is using "100% CPU" for minutes, so I suspected something rather inefficient as `sed` is usually quite efficient.

Here is my isolated test case (the file was copied from a temporary file that `supportconfig` would create):

```sh
# time sed -i -e '   s/\(.*[P|p]ass"\?:\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g; s/\(.*[P|p]assword"\?:\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;     s/\(.*[P|p]ass[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;        s/\(.*[P|p]assword[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;    s/\(.*PASS=\).*/\1*REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g; s/\(.*_PASSWORD[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;      s!\(<user_password>\).*\(</user_password>\)!\1*REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*\2!g;   s/\(^ProxyUser[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g; s/\(^credentials[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;      s/\(secret[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;    s/\({'\''[s]*password'\''}[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*'\''\).*\('\'';\)/\1*REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*\2/g;  s/\(.*password[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;        s/\(.*password_in[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;     s/\(^echo -n\).*\(> \/sys\/kernel\/config\/target\/.*auth\/password.*\)/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG* \2/g' /tmp/uuu

real    6m53.283s
user    6m45.909s
sys     0m0.129s
# wc /tmp/uuu
  12234  123937 2711538 /tmp/uuu
```

So it took almost 7 minutes to process a 2.7MB text file.
The only special thing may be that the text lines are rather long.

I suspect that the `.*` is causing massive backtracking when matching, and maybe the programmer was just a bit lazy providing better regular expressions.
While `sed` was running, I also did an `strace`, but that basically just showed `brk` system calls (memory allocation).

So what might cause the terrible performance, and is there a way to improve it?

I can't provide the original input file as it seems to contain URLs for non-free downloads, unfortunately.
But I could try proposals for a different `sed` invocation on the file I saved.

`sed`version being used is `sed-4.2.2-7.3.1.x86_64`.

## Transformation for readability

Fixing the `[P|p]` to `[Pp]`, a more readable version of the `sed` command will look like this:

```sed
sed -i -e '
s/\(.*[Pp]ass"\?:\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(.*[Pp]assword"\?:\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(.*[Pp]ass[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(.*[Pp]assword[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(.*PASS=\).*/\1*REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(.*_PASSWORD[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s!\(<user_password>\).*\(</user_password>\)!\1*REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*\2!g;
s/\(^ProxyUser[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(^credentials[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(secret[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\({'\''[s]*password'\''}[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*'\''\).*\('\'';\)/\1*REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*\2/g;
s/\(.*password[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(.*password_in[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(^echo -n\).*\(> \/sys\/kernel\/config\/target\/.*auth\/password.*\)/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG* \2/g'
```

So obviously the purpose is to remove sensitive information like passwords from the log file.

**Note:** it seems the code block does parse `*` as markup in some cases...

## Trying a solution

Doing the modifications suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77820459/6607497, I got these results:

```sh
### original version of regex
# /tmp/uuu.sh

real    6m39.697s
user    6m39.092s
sys     0m0.032s
### modified version of regex
# /tmp/uuu.sh

real    0m0.237s
user    0m0.226s
sys     0m0.009s
```

When reducing the original input file to a smaller test case (about 9kB), the effect is still there, but less dramatic:

```sh
### original regexes
# /tmp/uuu.sh /tmp/eeee

real    0m0.119s
user    0m0.115s
sys     0m0.004s
### improved regexes
# /tmp/uuu.sh /tmp/eeee

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Here is the obfuscated and trimmed test input file as BASE64 (due to very long lines); pipe input into `base64 -d | gzip -d` to decode:

```text
# gzip < /tmp/eeee | base64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```

## Another Experiment

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/77833314/6607497, I tried to find out the actual timing differences, so I created a file with one million random printable ASCII characters (assuming it will be large enough to show a difference).

Not knowing what's actually in the file, I tried the "foo variants" using `grep` (assuming `grep` would show similar effects):

```sh
> time grep -q 'foo' /dev/shm/random.txt

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.001s
> time grep -q '.*foo' /dev/shm/random.txt

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.006s
> time grep -q 'foo.*' /dev/shm/random.txt

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
> time grep -q '.*foo.*' /dev/shm/random.txt

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Surprisingly there was *no difference* (and "foo" is not present in the file).
However there are matches for `fo.` (position:match) like this:

```text
763:foH
3440:foY
13789:fo;
...
958405:foE
965938:foF
967142:foD
```

The complete list is:

```sh
> grep -o fo. /dev/shm/random.txt | tr '\n' ' '
foH foY fo; fof fom foa foj foV fo9 foy fo2 foP fo9 fo4 foC for fox foG foh foa foj fo} fod foq fo} foR fow fok foy foh fo> foy foK fo` foW fo2 foJ foL fo+ for fo~ foP fo` foq fo[ foi fos fo~ fo: fo. foy foD fo@ fo= fo+ foT foO fo] fok fo^ foa foh fod foA fo8 foJ foX fo` foN fo3 foS fo* fog foK fo6 fof fo4 fog foE fo* foO fo] foB fo< fo# fo" fow fo8 fo> foA fo+ foO fog foj foD fo: for fo1 fo. fo' foi foO foW foE foF foD >
```

So I tried to use `sed` actually:

```sh
> time sed -n -e 's/foo/XXX/p' /dev/shm/random.txt

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.004s
> time sed -n -e 's/.*foo/XXX/p' /dev/shm/random.txt

real    1m20.032s
user    1m19.818s
sys     0m0.016s
> time sed -n -e 's/foo.*/XXX/p' /dev/shm/random.txt

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.006s
> time sed -n -e 's/.*foo.*/XXX/p' /dev/shm/random.txt

real    1m19.490s
user    1m19.425s
sys     0m0.017s
```

Hunting for the constant string showed the same performance as `grep` had, but prefixing `.*` showed a performance of almost 80000 times worse!
In contrast suffixing `.*` had almost no effect, and using both, prefix and suffix `.*` is basically the same as just using the prefix variant.

Versions being used:
`grep-2.16-4.6.1.x86_64`
`sed-4.2.2-7.3.1.x86_64`

### Not confusing enough?

Then I had the idea to quantify the performance hit of using prefix `.*`, so I decided to truncate the random file to just using the first 1000 characters:

```sh
> head -c1000 /dev/shm/random.txt >/dev/shm/random-1000.txt
> time sed -n -e 's/foo/XXX/p' /dev/shm/random-1000.txt

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s
> time sed -n -e 's/.*foo/XXX/p' /dev/shm/random-1000.txt

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s
> time sed -n -e 's/foo.*/XXX/p' /dev/shm/random-1000.txt

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s
> time sed -n -e 's/.*foo.*/XXX/p' /dev/shm/random-1000.txt

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.000s
```

To my big surprise, there was no noticeable difference now!?

I was thinking:

- Is it because of the missing end-of-line character?
- Does `sed` have some internal limited buffer that allows fast matching, but when exceeding that matching will be very slow?

So I repeated the tests after having added an end-of-line character:
Still it was about the same fast performance!

Then I re-did the experiments with sizes of 10000 and 100000 characters:
For 10000 characters the `.*`prefix was only 9 times slower than the 1000 character variant, but the 100000 characters was about 90 times slower than as the 10000 character variant.

So my conclusion is that `sed` has some fixed internal "fast buffer".
Is that correct?

Comment: `I suspect that the .* is causing massive backtracking`. So what happens when you do the trivial rewrite to remove it? And it is obvious that at least 9 of the `s///` can be trivially refactored into just one.

Comment: It also appears to rewrite the same line multiple times. For example, if I change the `/g` to `/gp` on each line, it prints three (identical) lines for the input `password = foo bar`

Comment: not relevant to the problem but `[P|p]` probably doesn't match what is intended.

Comment: PCRE regexp can have an exponential execution time when there are many `.*`-like expressions in the regexp, like here, especially on big files. There are two solutions : not using PCRE engine but deterministic ones (RE2), but I am not sure sed supports that, or simply make the regexp more deterministic manually (most common solution). The later is often rather cumbersome though. You can also mitigate the exponential execution by splitting the input in parts if possible (so the backtracking is limited).

Comment: Honestly, here, in most of replacement cases, a regexp is not even needed : having multiple regexps `.*word.*` is fundamentally inefficient (by several order of magnitude). Indeed, one can just search a bag of words in each line and replace the whole line. The later is far more efficient.

Comment: Note you can also use quantifiers to mitigate the issue. It generally not solve the problem but can reduce the runtime in your specific case. By default, quantifiers are greedy. You can make them lazy. The later can be much faster when the captured expression is small (but also significantly slower otherwise, so be careful).

Comment: As said, it's actually not my code, but I'm curious, so I can benchmark any alternatives suggested helping to find the "best" answer.

Comment: when you benchmark my suggested rewrites what are the results?

Comment: @jhnc Could you be specific how the sed command should look like?

Comment: 1) exactly as the original but with the unnecessary `.*` removed. 2) exactly as the original but with all similar regexp combined using the (non-posix) `\|` operator and suitable parentheses

Comment: I don't know who down-voted the question, but what are "unnecessary `.*`" inside a capture group (`\(...\)`)? If I remove those, then the `\1` substitution will be different.

Comment: Technically, `.*foo.*` is not the same as `foo.*` but that seems unlikely to be a issue here. As an aside, any `s///` that matches `foo.*` does not need `/g` since there can be no other matches, but removing it won't improve performance here.

Comment: the substitution is different but the resulting string is the same - any string replaced by itself doesn't change

Comment: You can reduce backtracking simply by anchoring the initial `.*` to beginning of string (i.e. `^.*`).  I'd probably put the sed program in a file at this point, rather than writing it all as `-e` arguments.

Comment: (`.*foo.*` matches the final occurrence of "foo"; `foo.*` matches the first occurrence - but if the input ever contains two occurrences (eg. `wanted1 foo secret wanted2 foo secret`), the original code would fail to sanitise fully (`wanted1 foo secret wanted2 foo hidden`, while with the change it would (`wanted1 foo hidden`))

Comment: See also ["sed performance issues" on github](https://github.com/openSUSE/supportutils/issues/187)

Comment: @JérômeRichard sed doesn't support PCREs and neither does any other mandatory POSIX tool. Only the GNU grep variant of the mandatory POSIX tool `grep` has a `-P` option to support PCREs.

Comment: You should never include `-i` in a question unless the question is specifically about `-i` as it'll trash the input file on each execution of the command so it's bad for testing/debugging potential solutions, and it adds a layer of uncertainty around whether THAT is the cause of whatever problem you're asking about or not. Please remove the `-i` and re-do your timing then [edit] your question to show the result if you still see a problem.

Comment: You say "I can't provide the original input file as it seems to contain URLs for non-free downloads," but you CAN create a [mcve] with an input file that includes some URLs you invent (e.g. at `http://example.com`) plus the expected output given that input that we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: @EdMorton I realized what the `-i` does after having posted the question, so I redid the tests (without `-i`) with very similar results. Also as the confidential data to replace have about the same length as `*REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*`, the test would be valid even with `-i` I guess. -- Anyway I'll update the question.

Comment: Are you trying to get a faster command or just asking if regexps that match longer strings (`a.b.*`) are slower than those that match shorter strings (`a.b`)?

Comment: I thought it's obvious: I'm asking what is causing the seemingly slowness, and thus (indirectly) how to "fix" it.

Comment: Without sample input and expected output I doubt you'll get many suggested improvements. To provide sample input you could post a (awk?) script that generates some large number (100,000?) of lines that look like your expected input (don't post 100,000 input lines, post a script that can generate 100,000 input lines) and then for the expected output you could post, say, the first 20 lines of output given that input.

Comment: I thought you had provided a way for us to get a few lines of sample input if we ran `base64 -d file | gzip -d` on it but when I run `base64 -d file | gzip -d | grep pass` it outputs `password= *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*` so that appears to be the output from some input we haven't seen yet. If/when you do provide sample input, please add the expected output given that input.

Comment: I see the output from `base64 -d file | gzip -d` is XML containing, among other things, multi-line free-form text descriptions. Given that, a solution like that `sed` command is likely to corrupt the data since it'd convert `<description>Checks if password == valid before processing</description>` to `<description>Checks if password =*REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*` and it'd have the usual problems of handling multiple tags on a line, values split across lines, etc. that occur with such attempts.

Comment: So how fast it executes isn't the biggest issue it has, you may want to get an XML-aware solution or at least one that can make a good attempt at isolating the correct target text between the right tags, etc. if that's not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, those `.*` matches were very bad for performance:

After removing those, the performance did improve enormously (like factor 1500):

```text
real    0m0.230s
user    0m0.225s
sys     0m0.005s
```

For reference this is the canonical command used (I also dropped `-i` to preserve the input file for repeatable tests):

```sh
time sed -e '
s/\([Pp]ass"\?:\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\([Pp]assword"\?:\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\([Pp]ass[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\([Pp]assword[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(PASS=\).*/\1*REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(_PASSWORD[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s!\(<user_password>\).*\(</user_password>\)!\1*REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*\2!g;
s/\(^ProxyUser[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(^credentials[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(secret[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\({'\''[s]*password'\''}[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*'\''\).*\('\'';\)/\1*REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*\2/g;
s/\(password[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(password_in[[:space:]]*=\).*/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*/g;
s/\(^echo -n\).*\(> \/sys\/kernel\/config\/target\/.*auth\/password.*\)/\1 *REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG* \2/g
' "${1:-/tmp/uuu}" >"${2:-/dev/null}"
```

Comment: The script may run faster if you remove the `.*`s but it'll no longer work as the strings that match those `.*`s which the script is trying to remove will not be removed, they'll still be present in the output.

Comment: You are not saying that my "solution" is wrong, right? I removed the leading `.*`, but not the trailing one. Obviously if I dropped the trailing one the substitutions would be kind of useless. Still the changes done so far had a *huge* effect of efficiency.

Comment: I thought you were saying that removing all the `.*`s would speed it up. I didn't notice the script in your answer being any different from the ones in the question as I was just looking at the trailing `.*s` so I thought you were just showing the script from the question again for some reason.

Comment: Removing the leading `.*`s may result in different output than with them present so just watch out for that, e.g. given input of `fooPassBarPassStuff` using `s/\(.*Pass\).*/\1/` would output `fooPassBarPass` while `s/\(Pass\).*/\1/` would output `fooPass` so YMMV removing the `.*`s.

Comment: Does your modified script produce exactly the same output as the original script?

Comment: The question of correct output is a matter of possible inputs and substitution rules of course. Actually I don't know the possible inputs, but I suspect that your example given is slightly pathological. Generally it's hard to remove confidential information from arbitrary input. A `grep -i pass.*pass` on the original input file showed no matches.

Answer (score 0):

Regexps that try to match longer strings take longer to do execute than regexps that try to match shorter strings as they have more work to do so, yes, matching `.*foo.*` will take longer than matching `foo` (or `.*foo` or `foo.*`).

Without sample input it's hard to suggest a "best" approach but using GNU awk for the third arg to `match()` you could do something like (untested):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { repl = "*REMOVED BY SUPPORTCONFIG*" }
    /[Pp]ass|PASS|ProxyUser|credentials/ {
        line = $0
        if ( \
                match($0,/[Pp]ass(word)?("?:|[[:space:]]*=)/)     ||
                match($0,/(PASS|_PASSWORD[[:space:]]*)=/)         ||
                match($0,/^(ProxyUser|credentials)[[:space:]]*=/) ||
                match($0,/(secret|password(_in)?[[:space:]]*=/)   \
                ) {
            line = substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH) repl
        }
        else if ( \
                match($0,/(.*<user_password>).*(<\/user_password>.*)/,a) ||
                match($0,/(.*\{\047[s]*password\047}[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\047).*(\047;)/,a) ||
                match($0,"(^echo -n).*(> /sys/kernel/config/target/.*auth/password.*)",a)  \
                ) {
            line = a[1] repl a[2]
        }
        $0 = line
    }
    { print }
'
```

which would only test the more complicated regexps for lines that might match them and then only test those regexps til the first one that matches rather then testing all 14.

Comment: I think "*Regexps that match longer strings take longer to do that match than regexps that match shorter strings*" is too much of a simplification. For example it also applies for regexps that never match, and most significantly the "take longer" is by no means linear to the length of the attempted match, but *much* worse.

Comment: "that match" should have been "that try to match", thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved in sed version 4.3 and higher per https://savannah.gnu.org/news/?id=8726

> ========================================================
>
> NEWS
>
> - Noteworthy changes in release 4.3 (2016-12-30) [stable]
>
> ** Improvements
>
> sed's regular expression matching is now typically 10x faster

Accordingly, supportconfig on SLES15 and higher is unaffected due to sed version 4.4 being installed by default. SUSE engineering is evaluating the suggestions given to work around the issue for SLES12.